# require suggestions for creating a sql query

Tags: php, mysql

i am designing a lab reservation page. There i need some query to check for availability of time selected by the user. I am checking this by using:

```
select * from slotbook where start between $startTime and $endTime or end between $startTime and $endTime
```

where $startTime and $endTime are being posted from the php form. Till now its fine. But I want one more functionality i.e the $startTime should be atleast 10 mins greater than its nearest booked slot. That means if previously a slot was booked whose endTime is 1:30PM and the user submitted 1:35PM as a startTime of his booking, it should be checked. What addition to this query is required?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, why not just subtract 10 from $startTime and add 10 to $endTime before you run the query, thus giving you 10 minutes on either side of the selected time?

Comment: i don't think so. what do you say about this: "select * from slotbook where (start between $startTime and $endTime or end between $startTime and $endTime) and end > $extraTime" where $extraTime = $startTime-600, in seconds

Comment: Just to clarify, you are checking the db to see if there are any previously booked slots (within your parameters) and if there is, you will notify the user that they can't have it?

Comment: yes, additionally, there will be 10 mins extra for the lab management team to reset all the configurations of the devices, so the next lab should be booked 10 mins later than the previous one

Comment: Simpler is better. "select * from slotbook where start between $startTime and $endTime or end between $startTime2 and $endTime" where $startTime2=$startTime-600. Now if they have a startTime that is less than 10 minutes after the end of a set one, it will be flagged

Comment: where did you use $startTime2 in the query?

Comment: It's there on the second OR statement